# Socket io, mssql, node, expressjs in localhost cannot append data to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express, socket.io

I have very large data to fetch from sql server using node and broadcast the data to client in realtime using socket io.
I am able to get the data but the client cannot update the UI.

The data can be console logged in the browser. Why the data is not appended to html body.

The server is running locally. 
Using latest stable version of node , express and socket io @ 1.7.4
server.js

```
var fs = require("fs");
//const fse = require("fs-extra");
var compression = require('compression')
var Connection = require("tedious").Connection;
var Request = require("tedious").Request;
var path = require("path");
var TYPES = require("tedious").TYPES;
var sql = require("mssql"); 
var cors = require("cors");



var express = require("express"),
  app = express(),

  server = require("http").createServer(app);
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3001, "0.0.0.0");

app.use(cors());
app.use(compression())
var dbConfig = {
  user: "xxx",
  password: "xxx",
  server: "xxx",
  database: "xxx"
};

//Connect to the Database Instance
var cp = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
cp.connect(err => {
  console.log("Database error message +++++++++ " + err);
});

app.use(express.json());
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('echo',function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  var request = new sql.Request(cp);
  var statement =
"USE xxx; SELECT TOP 100000 * from xxxx";
request.stream = true;
request.query(statement);

request.on('recordset', columns => {
// Emitted once for each recordset in a query

})

request.on('row', row => {

  socket.emit("row",row);

})

request.on('error', err => {

})
request.on('done', result => {


})
});
```

Index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
         <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"
        integrity="sha256-BTlTdQO9/fascB1drekrDVkaKd9PkwBymMlHOiG+qLI="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001",{
                transports: ['websocket','polling']
            });
            var body = $("body");
            socket.on("connect",function () {

            })
            socket.emit('echo', 'this is a message');   
            socket.on("row",function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                 body.append(data);
                })


        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using express, So no need to use http explicitly.
Hope this may help to solve your issue

```
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io')

const app = express();
const port = 3001;
let server = app.listen(port, () => { // Create server & Listen port 3001
  console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`);
  let io = socketIO(app, { pingInterval: 10000, pingTimeout: 5000 }); // Create server with express app
  io.on('connect', (socket) => { // Once connection established, You got socket object use this for your future data transfer
    console.log('Socket connected');
    socket.on('echo', data => {
      console.log('echo data')
    )
    socket.emit('row', {any: "any row data"})
  })
});
```

UI:
In html you may add ul to append your data

```
<body>
   <ul id="container">
   </ul>
  // your scripts..
  socket.on("row", (data) => {
    $('#container').append(`<li> ${data} </li>`)
  });
</body>
```

Comment: I still cannot display the data.

Comment: @Karan It's working. Myself i have setup local env and tested

Comment: have you tried the way i m fetching, i have set the request.stream =true, so the rows from the table is fetched and passed as stream to the client.

Comment: No, So what you have received in your UI (ex.  socket.on("row", (data) => {console.log(data)}); ).

Comment: In the UI the data is not displayed, if i don' t set request.stream = true, i have to wait for about 2-3 mins, i cannot update UI in realtime. in console i get 10,000 object in realtime without any delay, i think i have to use web worker.

Comment: Ok, Understood. I'll try to reproduce the issue and let you know.